# Python : Color scatter by datetimes column with Bokeh

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh, scatter, colormap

With Bokeh, I'm trying to color scatter with datetime values and create a colorbar with a datetime scale.

(something like this)  :

[Origin pro Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW44o.png)

A sample of the timeseries  :

```
    Date                Rate    Level
    01/01/2019 08:59    38.3    -19.7
    02/01/2019 09:04    39.1    -21
    01/01/2019 09:09    40.7    -31
    01/01/2019 09:14    42.1    -15
    01/01/2019 09:19    43.6    -14
    01/01/2019 09:24    46.8    -19.7
```

I tried to plot Rate=f(Level) :

```
cwd=os.getcwd()
delimit_file=','
fichier = 'qsv1.csv'

qsv = pd.read_csv(fichier,delimiter=delimit_file, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
qsv['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(qsv['Date'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')


p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, plot_height=500,)

source = ColumnDataSource(qsv)


exp_cmap = LinearColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", 
                             low = min(qsv["Date"]), 
                             high = max(qsv["Date"]))

p.circle("Rate", "Level", source=source, line_color=None,
        fill_color={"field":"Date", "transform":exp_cmap})
#p.line("Date", "QS_conv", source=source, color='navy', legend='moyenne glissante')

bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=exp_cmap, location=(0,0))
p.add_layout(bar, "left")

show(p)
```

But i get :

```
ValueError: expected a value of type Real, got 2019-01-01 00:04:00 of type Timestamp
```

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it works by converting datetime in ms

```
qsv['actualDateTime'] = qsv['Date'].astype(np.int64) / int(1e6)

exp_cmap1 = LinearColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", 
                             low = min(qsv['actualDateTime']), 
                             high = max(qsv['actualDateTime']))

p1.circle("Debit, "Niveau", source=source, line_color=None,
        fill_color={"field":"actualDateTime", "transform":exp_cmap1})

bar1 = ColorBar(color_mapper=exp_cmap1, location=(0,0), formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(days=["%d/%m/%y"]), label_standoff=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please always include a full stack trace, not just one line. Presumably, this message is from setting, e.g.

```
low = min(qsv["Date"])
```

The configuration properties of the linear color mapper do not expect anything other than plain numbers. The underlying units of datetimes in Bokeh are *Milliseconds since Epoch* so that is what you should convert your datetime values to before passing to the color mapper.